# Stop and Start default with Jquery

Tags: jquery, preventdefault

I'm trying to stop the default event, and then execute it after running a couple of function. But It doesnt work

```
 $(#form_id).submit(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       get_hours(); // the function that i need to call
       document.form_name.submit();
});
```

but before the get_hours(); could be executed, the form is already submitted. How do i go about making this work. Please help

Comment: You are missing the quotes in selector.

Change `$(#form_id)` to `$('#form_id')`.

Comment: Comment out the form submission (last code line). Does it still submit the form at all? If so, then you have narrowed the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you are preventing default on the .submit() event.

Try doing it on the .click() event. Like this:

```
 $( "#form_id button" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  get_hours();
  document.form_name.submit();
});
```

You can replace the 'click' with whatever event is taken to submit the form. Also replace the 'button' to the selector of the item that triggers the event.

Comment: thanks for the response. I tried this earlier. The problem is get_hours is an ajax call. So as soon as i click on the button, it runs the function, but before the ajax call is completed it already starts submitting.

Comment: in that case, add your call to `document.form_name.submit()` on the 'success' handling of your ajax call... or make your ajax call 'synchronous' forcing the function to wait for the response before continuing with the form submit()